# image texture doesnt appear after render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, image, properties

[image][image][image]The imagetexture of an object appears in the viewport shading rendered but not with viewing render or after exporting.  I use blender render. Thanks for help.
(first picture shows the view render, second viewport shading rendered, third texture properties, fourth the export settings)

[image: 9.png]

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add images of the issue, screenshots of your render settings and image settings. The more info, the better to help you.

Comment: are you talking about an object not appearing or about a texture on an object? for the first, make sure that the camera icon of the object is enabled in the Outliner, you need to display the camera icons first (click on the funnel icon) on the top of the Outliner

Comment: Thanks for comment. The texture on an object doesnt appear

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: the reason is anywhere at the particle properties. When i copy the object and delete the settings there is a texture. But no exactly idea for the reason?!